# refresh token API error "secretOrPrivateKey must have a value"

Tags: node.js, typescript, jwt, nestjs, refresh-token

When a user logs into the API generates a token so that he has access to other endpoints, but the token expires in 60sec, I made a function to generate a new valid token using the old token (which was stored in the database), but when I'm going to generate a new valid token I'm getting the secretOrPrivateKey must have a value error

The function refreshToken use function login to generate a new token

### Nest error:

```
secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value
   at Object.module.exports [as sign] (C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:107:20)
   at JwtService.sign (C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\node_modules\@nestjs\jwt\dist\jwt.service.js:28:20)
   at AuthService.login (C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\src\auth\auth.service.ts:18:39)
   at TokenService.refreshToken (C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\src\token\token.service.ts:39:37)
   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
   at TokenController.refreshToken (C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\src\token\token.controller.ts:12:16)
   at C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
   at C:\Users\talis\nova api\myflakes_api\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17
```

### My code:

Function refreshToken in the file token.service.ts

```
async refreshToken(oldToken: string) {
    let objToken = await this.tokenRepository.findOne({hash: oldToken})
    if (objToken) {
        let user = await this.userService.findOneOrFail({email:objToken.email})
        return this.authService.login(user)
    } else {
        return new UnauthorizedException(MessagesHelper.TOKEN_INVALID)
    }
}
```

Function login in the file auth.service.ts

```
async login(user: UsersEntity) {
    const payload = { email: user.email, sub: user.idUser }
    const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload) // here!!!
    this.tokenService.save(token, user.email)
    return {
        token: token
    };
}
```

Error is on `const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload)`

Here is the file jwt.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";
import { jwtConstants } from "../constants";
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor() {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            ignoreExpiration: false,
            secretOrKey: jwtConstants.secret,
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: { sub: any; email: any; }) {
        return { id: payload.sub, email: payload.email}
    }
}
```

And here local.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { MessagesHelper } from "src/helpers/messages.helper";
import { AuthService } from "../auth.service";

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super({ usernameField: 'email' });
    }

    async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
        if(!user) 
            throw new UnauthorizedException(MessagesHelper.PASSWORD_OR_EMAIL_INVALID)
        
        return user;
    }
}
```

this is the AuthModule where is JwtModule.register

```
@Module({
    imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    TokenModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
      controllers: [AuthController],
      providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
      exports: [JwtModule, AuthService]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Guys i tried to use images, but i'm new user and i still don't have a reputation, sorry.

Comment: what if you supply `secret` to `.sign` method as well? like so `this.jwtService.sign(payload, { secret: jwtConstants.secret })`

Comment: actually, can you show us how you've loaded the `JwtModule`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doing what [@Micael Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5290447/micael-levi) mentioned in the comments worked for me, so it would be:

```
const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload, jwtConstants.secret)
```

For future reference, I encountered this issue despite my environment variables being defined **(process.env.SECRET_KEY being undefined was a common problem seen in other similar questions**). So what I did to fix mine was:

```
return {
      access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload, { secret: process.env.JWT_SEC }),
};
```

Comment: i do not know why but i still get this error